# Sheet metal animation

Tags: animation

Probably a very niche question but what would be the proper way to animate the transition from the flat sheet metal state to the bent state (modeled in Fusion360 so not a really good topology) ? I've started looking around and using the AnimAll plugin and Bones/Armature but I need to have a radius in the bend which i didn't figured out a way to do it.

Attached : Images of the flat and bent state of the sheet metal.

[image: Flat sheet metal]

[image: Bent sheet metal]

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe use a segmented bone for the fold?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31621/folding-a-cube-animation https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57976/how-to-simulate-miura-fold/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6767/how-to-make-folding-origami-animation/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161322/suggestions-to-make-a-uwrap-animation-with-this-ball-model/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213540/fold-a-plane-then-fold-again https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194153/rigging-technique-for-flexible-cardboard-packaging https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28829/

Comment: Hey! I recently used this animation to animate a cardboard box. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1em_ijMvUk I know Youtúbe videos are not preferred for Stackexchange answers but it would be a shame not sharing this

Comment: @EvripidisLalissidis that's the tutorial I've looked at, the problem isn't really the fold its more the radius that the fold has to make...